# Trying to install aimeos bundle in symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I try to install aimeos bundle for symfony and i get these errors:

> Your version of PHP, 5.5.1, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot
>   safely perfo rm certificate validation, we strongly suggest you
>   upgrade. Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
>   not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for aimeos/aimeos-symfony ~2016.04 -> satisfiable by aimeos/aimeos-symfony[2016.04.1].
>       - aimeos/aimeos-symfony 2016.04.1 requires aimeos/ai-symfony dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min imum-stability setting

This is my composer.json file on the root of my symfony folder:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},

"prefer-stable": true,
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {

    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "aimeos/aimeos-symfony": "~2016.04"

},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget",
        "Aimeos\\ShopBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installBundle",
        "Aimeos\\ShopBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setupDatabase"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget",
        "Aimeos\\ShopBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installBundle",
        "Aimeos\\ShopBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setupDatabase"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.3.9"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can someone have a look at my composer.json file because i don't know if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

The 2016.04.1 version of the Aimeos bundle for Symfony references accidentally other dev-master packages and therefore requires this line in your composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

A new version fixing the problem will be released tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you But i don't know if my composer.json file is correct

Comment: You should remove the platform -> php setting as this usually causes some trouble